# How to do error handling with vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, stdvector

This is probably a noob question, but I am a bit confused.

I have a block of code that looks like this:

```
std::vector<MyObject*> datas;
try
{
 MyObject data = get_me_data();
 MyObject* dat=&data;
 datas.push_back(dat);
}
catch (...) {}
do_something_with_datas(datas);
```

The issue is that function after try/catch code that should handle std::vector does not work properly as I am getting nonsense from the function.

I think the issue is that dat goes out of scope in try block, so state of what it points is undefined and I really shouldn't have used MyObject* dat=&data?
I am also uncertain if vector is cleared properly.

Can someone please point me at right direction? I have some algorithm that creates bunch of MyObject data objects. I wish to pack pointers to them into a vector and process them after the try/catch code.

This is simplified code, actual algorithm uses MyObject* because the code implements iterative algorithm that updates dat object before pushing them into vector. So main issue here is how to make get_me_data() function give me a pointer to data, and not the data.
Would I need to use new operator at the line when it creates the object?

I am new to C++, and I am certain there are many better ways to implement this, can someone explain how would move semantics be used here. What I understood from move constructors is that they turn rvalue into lvalue and provide a more efficient copy, i.e they'd move pointers that point to array fields and "neglect" original object, so the memory would be "moved" to a new object, instead of copied. I am not sure if that'd work with the code I wrote as the idea is to iteratively update fields of MyObject. As all classes in the code need MyObject as their input, it made little sense to me to move it around and ensuring that every class in the package is moveable. It seems much easier to have one MyObject and to pass a pointer to it across the whole package, and not be bothered too much about ownership. Am I horribly wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Why do you use vector of pointers? `std::vector<MyObject> datas;  datas.push_back(get_me_data_pointer());` would work

Comment: `&data` is the address of the local object `data`. The address ceases to be valid as soon as you leave the scope `data` was defined in, which means that by the time you're out of the `try` block your vector is containing pointers to invalid data.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. It's iterative algorithm, before it's pushed into vector, dat object gets iteratively updated. This code works fine when there's one data object. Issue is now when I need to put things into for loop. So algorithm is: 

data =set_initial_guess()
do_something_to_data(&data)

As data object needs to be updated many times, it's more efficient to handle pointer to it, but code here doesn't work because probably memory that it points at is gone when try gets out of scope. I think I need to look into get_me_data_pointer() function (set initial guess) to return  *

Comment: @NathanPierson Yeah, that's my guess. So dumb question is, how do I turn MyObject into MyObject* properly. The function that creates is complicated, but eventually calls MyObject constructor, and I feel it'd be bad idea to switch line in that function to retval = new MyObject(...); return retval;

Comment: "_As data object needs to be updated many times, it's more efficient to handle pointer to it,_": With move semantics there is rarely any point to this and even if there is, you should use `std::unique_ptr<MyObject>` instead of `MyObject*`. I suggest you ask how to implement this design efficiently instead of focusing on this particular approach.

Comment: You pass objects to other functions usually by-reference, not by-pointer. What I meant with move semantics is just the step of putting the object into the vector. You can put the object in the vector first and then pass references to it to functions to operate on or you can create an object first, pass it via reference to operate on, and then finally copy/move it into the vector. You are not giving enough details about your design to give any more detailed explanation. You should show some [mre] of how you are using the object which also demonstrates why you think pointers are necessary.

Comment: Also, you usually don't need to do anything in order to have classes be movable. Always try to follow the rule-of-zero and encapsulate anything that can't follow it as narrowly as possible, and you will always have all special member functions for copy/move implicitly defined with the correct behavior. See also the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the issue is that dat goes out of scope in try block

Your hunch is correct.

> I am also uncertain if vector is cleared properly.

Although this cannot be determined, based on the shown code this is very likely. This happens very often in code that suffers from a common problem called "Pointless Use Of Pointers".

There's nothing in the shown code that requires pointers. Maybe there might be some other reason, that's not shown, but as as the shown code is concerned there is no reason why the vector cannot simply be:

```
std::vector<MyObject> datas;
```

And the try/catch block gets reduced to:

```
datas.push_back(get_me_data());
```

It's unclear whether this still needs exception handling. Whether it does or does not everything now works correctly, either way. Finally: whether or not the "vector is cleared properly" is now a completely moot point. It will be automatically cleared properly. The `std::vector` will make sure that its contents gets correctly cleared when it is destroyed.

> I have some algorithm that creates bunch of MyObject data objects.

Great, here they are, in their entirety: `std::vector<MyObject>`. Just say "No" to pointless use of pointers.